# Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2013, keep last tree state open

Tags: treeview, visual-studio-2013, source-control-explorer

I like some of the new things in Visual Studio 2013. Some stuff is annoying, but I guess they try to push or pull people toward different practices.

But what's weird is the source control explorer when I open VS2013 is completely collapsed. In VS2010 it was always open to the last state I had it in. This becomes more and more annoying as I use VS2013. I constantly have to click through. Sure I can open recent projects, but come on. How can I keep my tree open :)?

On the right is what it always opens to, in VS2010 the tree would look like on the left if that's how it was when I closed it.

[image: Collapsed tree:(]

Comment: I'm sad that this hasn't received an answer, because this still drives me crazy. how could people not up-vote this and find an answer... well I know how they could 'not find an answer' :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had the same problem.
Found this option in Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server: Open Source Control Explorer to the most recent folder

[image]